# Jquery table reload on insert

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I am following this [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/). What I am trying to do is have it so that when the tables in the database are affected (insert, delete, update) the tables on my application will refresh without having to hit <kbd>F5</kbd>, or the refresh button. I followed the tutorial to the tee and no luck. Nothing happens. I would really appreciate if some one can look over my code and see if there any problems with?

```
<head>
    <link href="core/styles/secondary.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajaxsetup({
            cache: false
        })
        var ajax_load = "<img class='loading' src='core/images/load.gif' alt='Loading...'/>

        var loadURL="inoffice.php";
            $("#start_que").click(function(){
                $("#que").html(ajax_load).load(loadURL);
            });
     </script>
```

This is the table code for inoffice.php I am echo'ing two tables from the same table in the database but with different views (is null, IS NOT NULL)

```
<body id="que">
<?php
echo "Waiting";
echo 
    "<table border='2'>
    <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>A Number</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Why</th>
    <th>Student Comments</th>
    <th>Additional Requirements</th>
    <th>Signintime</th>
    <th>Staff Member</th>
    <th>Click if ready!</th>
    </tr>"
    ;

    foreach($result as $row)
    {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td> <a href=student.php?anum=" . $row['anum'] . " target='_blank'>" .$row['anum'] . " </a></td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['first'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['last'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['why'] . "</td>";  
  echo "<td>" . $row['comments'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['additional_req'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['signintime'] . "</td>";
  echo "
        <td>    <form action='counselor.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "' method='post' target='_new'>
                    <select name='namedrop'>
                        <option value=''>Counselor Name</option> 
                        <option value=''></option>
                        <option value=''><option>
                        <option value=''></option>
                        <option value=''></option>
                        <option value=''></option>
                        <option value=''></option>
                        <option value=''></option>
                        <option value=''></option>
                    </select>
            </td>

            <td> <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Start Session' id='start_que'></td>
            </form> </td>";
}
```

The button called Session Start with the id start_que is the submit button. Once that button is hit then the second table becomes populated. The code for the second table :

```
echo 
    "<table border='2'>
    <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>A Number</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Why</th>
    <th>Student Comments</th>
    <th>Signintime</th>
    <th>Staff Member</th>
    <th>Counselor Start Time</th>
    </tr>"
    ;

    foreach($result2 as $row2)
    {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row2['id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><a href=student.php?anum=" . $row2['anum'] . " target='_blank'>" .$row2['anum'] . " </a></td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row2['first'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row2['last'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row2['why'] . "</td>"; 
  echo "<td>" . $row2['comments'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row2['signintime'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row2['counselorname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row2['counselor_start_time'] . "</td>";
}

echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

From the tutorial posted above from my understanding once I click the button with start_que then the first table shows one less field, then the second table loads a new DOM but for some reason the desired affect is not happening.

Any help would be great thank you.

Comment: You should have two separate files here. mainpage.php that has the code for the first table, then inoffice.php that lists only the html for the second table that you are loading via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue at first glance seems to be that you are trying to attach dom event handlers before the dom has rendered. Wrap all of your code inside `$(document).ready()` This function will be called when the dom is ready, and then your event handlers can be attached.

Other than that, you missed some quotes and semi-colons and the function name should be `ajaxSetup` instead of `ajaxsetup`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            cache: false
        });

        var ajax_load = "<img class='loading' src='core/images/load.gif' alt='Loading...' />";

        var loadURL = "inoffice.php";

        $("#start_que").click(function () {
            $("#que").html(ajax_load).load(loadURL);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Edit: In your explanation, you said the first table is from **inoffice.php**, but your code lists **inoffice.php** as the url that you are loading the second table from.